# Why would a battery have a declared "LSL" ("lower service limit"?) for internal resistance?

Tags: batteries, internal-resistance

[LG's spec sheet for the BL-42D1F lithium ion battery](https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-accessories/lg-bl-42d1f-g5-battery) (that's the battery that goes with their G5 phone) states:

```
Internal Resistance:
Average: 67 mΩ
LSL: 47 mΩ
USL: 93 mΩ
```

I understand that a battery's internal resistance will increase over its lifetime, rendering the battery "less usable" (the increased internal resistance will mean that the battery will present a lower potential difference at its terminals whenever it provides current.). Hence, declaring an "upper service limit" makes sense.

But I thought that the "ideal internal resistance" of a battery was 0Ω (zero ohms) [(an ideal voltage source must have zero internal resistance)](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/measuring-internal-resistance-of-batteries/internal-resistance).

So why does LG (or anyone!) specify a lower service limit for internal resistance?

[(The spec sheet for the battery is also on the wayback machine.)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221203192058/https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-accessories/lg-bl-42d1f-g5-battery)